# Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Then which of the following statements implies that $f(0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

> Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Then which of the
>   following statements implies that $f(0)=0$?
>
> (A)$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^n dx=0.$
>
> (B)$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(x/n) dx=0.$
>
> (C)$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(nx) dx=0.$
>
> (D) None of the above.

(A)Suppose $f(x)=1-x, \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^n dx=-\frac{1}{n+1},$ which converges to zero. I tried to find the counter example for the (B) and (C). I couldn't find. please help me.

Answer (score 10):

(A) Consider the constant function $f(x) = 1/2$.

(B) $\int_0^1 f(x/n)\, dx = n \int_0^{1/n} f(y)\, dy \to f(0)$ (by the mean value theorem), hence condition (B) implies $f(0) = 0$.

(C) Consider $f(x) = \cos(2\pi x)$.

Comment: You are right. I thought about non-constant functions :'(. Thank you very much.

Comment: Added details for points (B) and (C).

Comment: @Rigel For all $n\in N$, by the MVT for integrals, there exists a $c\in(0,1/n)$, st $\int_0^{1/n} f(y)dy=f(c)(1/n-0)$. So $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n\int_0^{1/n} f(y)dy=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  f(c)=f(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}c)=f(0)$, since $f$ is continuous and $c\to0$ as $n\to \infty$. Is it right?

Comment: For every $n$ there exists $c_n \in (0, 1/n)$ such that...

Comment: Mr. Rigel can you tell me how to tackle this kind of problems? I mean where do you come up with the non-examples, is it through experience or something else?

Comment: It is enough to take a course in real analysis. After you study the various types of convergence, these examples are almost standard.

Answer (score 3):

B ) $0=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1f(\frac{x}{n})\, dx\\=\lim_{n\to \infty} f(\frac{c}{n})(1-0)  for \, some \, c\in (0,1)\\= \lim_{n\to \infty}f(\frac{c}{n})\\= f(0) \, since \, f \, is \, continuous .
$